# Polynomial problem...

Tags: polynomials

[image]

[image]

How is $p\ '(x)$ written in that solution? I understand that $p\ '(x)$ will be some $4$ degree polynomial but how did we find out that $2$ and $-2$ will be roots of $p\ '(x)$?

Comment: This is explicitly **not** an algebra/precalculus problem.

Comment: Will anyone care to tell why this question has been downvoted?

Comment: Probably because it was miscategorized.

Answer (score 3):

By the Division Algorithm, we know that there are some degree $2$ polynomials $Q_1, Q_2$ such that:
$$
P(x) = Q_1(x) \cdot (x - 2)^3 - 2 = Q_2(x) \cdot (x + 2)^3 + 2
$$

Differentiating each equation with product rule, we get:
\begin{align*}
P'(x) &= Q_1'(x) \cdot (x - 2)^3 + Q_1(x) \cdot 3(x - 2)^2
= (x - 2)^2 \cdot (\underbrace{(x - 2) Q_1'(x) + 3Q_1(x)}_{\textsf{some polynomial of degree $2$}}) \\ \\
P'(x) &= Q_2'(x) \cdot (x + 2)^3 + Q_2(x) \cdot 3(x + 2)^2
= (x + 2)^2 \cdot (\underbrace{(x + 2) Q_2'(x) + 3Q_2(x)}_{\textsf{some polynomial of degree $2$}})
\end{align*}

But then since $(x - 2)^2$ and $(x + 2)^2$ are coprime factors of $P'(x)$ and since $\deg P' = 4$, it follows that:
$$
P'(x) = K(x - 2)^2(x + 2)^2
$$
for some constant $K$, as desired.

Comment: How are they coprime factors? Even if they are coprime factors how does it imply the next step

Comment: @Cotton I believe by coprime, he means there is no polynomial that divides both $(x-2)^2$ and $(x+2)^2$.  He's shown $P'(x)$ has $2$ roots of $2$ and $2$ roots of $-2$.  That accounts for all $4$ roots.

Comment: @Mike How do we know that p(x) divides (x-2) and (x+2) in the first place?

Comment: @Cotton Do you mean how do we know that $P'(x)$ is divisible by $(x-2)$ and $(x+2)$?  The first line of math from this answer comes from the given information.  If dividing by $(x-2)^3$ gives a remainder of $-2$, then $[P(x)+2]$ is divisible by $(x-2)^3$.  Adriano then uses the product rule to show $P'(x)$ is then divisible by $(x-2)^2$.  And similarly for the other factor.

Answer (score -2):

Hint: Take derivative of that polynomial to get $16 - 8 x^2 + x^4=(x^2-4)^2$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain. Honestly, I have no clue.

Comment: Wasn't that polynomial arrived at by integrating $k(x-2)^2(x+2)^2$ in the first place?  This appears to be circular logic.

Comment: @Mike You are probably right. I misread the (confusing because of the figures) question in the first place. I guess I deserve the downvote then,.